# ZFCUser redirect to custom URL after login

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm trying to implement a function for the ZFCUser module that would detect the current URL, pass it on to the login page and once the users logs in, to redirect him to that URL.

Has anyone tried to do this?

I need to provide people with links to some areas of the site, but force them to log in before they can see them.

Thanks
Mac

Answer (score 3):

So, because ZfcUser (1.2) only allows redirection to a plain route (no parameters, no URI), I wrote my own RedirectCallback to override, as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Application;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception;
use Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response;
use ZfcUser\Options\ModuleOptions;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use Zend\Http\Request;

/**
 * Can redirect to the URI given during login.
 * N.B. Don't extend ZfcUser version since its members are all private.
 */
class RedirectUriCallback {

    /**
     * @var RouteInterface
     */
    protected $router;

    /**
     * @var Application
     */
    protected $application;

    /**
     * @var ModuleOptions
     */
    protected $options;

    /**
     * @param Application $application
     * @param RouteInterface $router
     * @param ModuleOptions $options
     */
    public function __construct(
    Application $application, RouteInterface $router, ModuleOptions $options
    ) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->application = $application;
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function __invoke() {
        $routeMatch = $this->application->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
        $redirect = $this->getRedirect($routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName(),
        $this->getRedirectRouteFromRequest());

        $response = $this->application->getResponse();
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $redirect);
        $response->setStatusCode(302);
        return $response;
    }

    protected function getRedirectRouteFromRequest() {
        $request = $this->application->getRequest();
        $redirect = $request->getQuery('redirect')? : $request->getPost('redirect');
        return $this->getSafeRedirect($redirect);
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize URI: through router and back.
     * @param $uri
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getSafeRedirect($uri) {
        if (!$uri) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            $request = new Request;
            $request->setUri($uri);
            $routeMatch = $this->router->match($request);
            if ($routeMatch instanceof RouteMatch) {
                return $this->router->assemble(
                $routeMatch->getParams(),
                ['name' => $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName()]
                );
            }
        } catch (Exception\RuntimeException $e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the url to redirect to based on current route.
     * If $redirect is set and the option to use redirect is set to true, it will return the $redirect url.
     *
     * @param string $currentRoute
     * @param mixed $redirect
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getRedirect($currentRoute, $redirect = null) {
        $redirect = $this->getSafeRedirect($redirect);
        if (!$this->options->getUseRedirectParameterIfPresent()) {
            $redirect = false;
        }
        if ($redirect) {
            return $redirect;
        }

        $route = 'zfcuser';
        switch ($currentRoute) {
            case 'zfcuser/register':
            case 'zfcuser/login':
                $route = $this->options->getLoginRedirectRoute();
                break;
            case 'zfcuser/logout':
                $route = $this->options->getLogoutRedirectRoute();
                break;
        }
        return $this->router->assemble([], ['name' => $route]);
    }

}
```

Then return the above class by overriding the `'zfcuser_redirect_callback'` factory, as follows:

```
        'zfcuser_redirect_callback' => function ($sm) {
            $router = $sm->get('Router');
            $application = $sm->get('Application');
            $options = $sm->get('zfcuser_module_options');
            return new RedirectUriCallback($application, $router,
            $options);
        },
```

(Good luck, no guarantees.)

Answer (score 2):

You can setup redirect after login in config file.

https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/config/zfcuser.global.php.dist

Copy above file into config/autoload/ and rename it to **zfcuser.global.php**

There you can find the key **login_redirect_route** for that purpose.

```
/**
 * Login Redirect Route
 *
 * Upon successful login the user will be redirected to the entered route
 *
 * Default value: 'zfcuser'
 * Accepted values: A valid route name within your application or a callback.
 *                  If callback used, it will receive the identity as the param
 *
 */
'login_redirect_route' => '/your-url',
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't have it hardcoded. It has to be the URL the users will go to, but because they have no permissions, they need to go through the login page first.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the line 83 of the user controller, you will see you can use a redirect parameter. [[User controller file]](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/Controller/UserController.php)

```
if ($this->getOptions()->getUseRedirectParameterIfPresent()) {
        $redirect = $request->getQuery()->get('redirect', (!empty($post['redirect'])) ? $post['redirect'] : false);
    } else {
        $redirect = false;
    }
```

Then, line 137 of the config file, you have to set the [redirect parameter if present config](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/config/zfcuser.global.php.dist).

Once this is done, you can use ?redirect=/whatever in your link for the login page.

Answer (score 0):

This is in the works and will probably be tagged withing the next few days.

We changed the behaviour a couple of weeks ago so that it used toRoute instead of toUrl because of security concern.

Please keep an eye on the github repo or follow me on twitter where i will tweet new releases: http://twitter.com/MrStroem

Comment: Yes, RedirectCallback.php only redirects to a plain route; you can't (as of ZfcUser 1.2) provide route parameters.  So you can do `asdf.com/login?redirect=zfcuser`.  Also of note, if using ZfcRbac module with RedirectStrategy, that passes to login the redirect URI (not route), so they're not handing off properly.